# Wie soll man den Ausdruck »etw. zu etw. tragen« lesen (oder übersetzen)?

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

I would like to get an accurate reading of the following sentence (from the book *Damals war es Friedrich*):

> Zu einer grünen Hose und einer roten Weste trug Polykarp eine blaue Zipfelmütze.

I am struggling with the expression *etw. zu etw. tragen.* Hitherto, my knowledge of *zu* is that it is translated as *for* or *to,* but those translations don’t seem to fit.  For this sentence, my initial guess is it is close to *with* or *in addition to,* which would result in the following translation of the sentence:

> Polykarp wore a blue pointed cap with a green pair of pants and a red vest.

Is my guess correct and if not, what does this expression mean?

Comment: Somewhat closer to the original, I would read it as _in addition to a pair of green trousers and a red waistcoat Polykarp wore a blue jelly bag cap_.

Comment: Okay.  With what you responded, I had also considered.

Comment: Note that this is **not** a special verb (_etw. zu etw. tragen_); instead, it is the plain transitive verb _tragen_ and, independently, a special meaning of _zu_ that can be used with other verbs as well: _Zum Spinat gab es Kartoffeln._

Comment: "Hitherto, my knowledge of *zu* is that it is translated as *for* or *to*, but those translations don’t seem to fit." Look up _zu_ in a dictionary to find its other meanings. E.g., in the [DWDS entry for *zu*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=zu), it’s A I 1 d, with lots of examples.

Answer (score 5):

Your translation sounds good.
The meaning of "zu" is that the cap is **going well** (or not so well, depending on personal opinion and taste) with trousers and waistcoat.

> […] wore a blue pointed cap [bag cap?] assorted with his green trousers and red waistcoat.

might reflect the meaning in English, and

> […] portait un bonnet pointu bleu assorti à son pantalon vert et son gilet rouge.

is a correct translation in French.

> Zu schwarzen Schuhen trägt man schwarze Socken.
>
> Zu dem Hemd kannst Du keine Krawatte tragen.

are two examples, where "zu" indicates a well-fitting combination or the opposite (according to the speaker).