# Why is 'Zur' used in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, word-usage

From a german magazine, *"Der Trend **zur** stylishen Kopfbedeckung aber bleibt."*

I don't understand why zur is used there. What is it's meaning in the sentence? The trend **to the** stylish headgear...
Does zur translate to 'to the'
If so, then it still doesn't make sense to me, or is this something that is just part of the german language that I should just accept?

Also: "*Perfekt **zum** Jeans-Blazer mit ausgefallenem Schnitt...."*

Could anyone please help?

Comment: The second part is a duplicate of http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25024 (although the only answer isn’t particularly good).

Comment: Regarding the first part, the same construction is used in English: _a trend toward sth_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to translate directly and the meaning in both sentences is a bit different.

The first sentence would best be translated as "But the trend *to wear* stylish headgear persits." In German "Der Trend zu/zur/zum s.th." is used like some sort of synonym, shortening the sentence by hiding the verb which will be conveyed by the context and only using the preposition.

The second sentence does rely on the context. Here I'd assume that they are talking about clothing and a specfic clothing item that can be worn perfectly with a jeans blazer. The sentence would then continue like "Perfekt zum Jeans-Blazer mit ausgefallenem Schnitt passt ein weißes T-Shirt".

In that case the meaning of "zum" would be translated like this "A white T shirt fits perfectly to a jeans blazer with a fancy clothing cut". Here "zum" acts as preposition connecting the blazer and the shirt in context with the verb "passen", essentialy replacing "to" in the English equivalent "fit s.th. to s.th.".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it makes sense now. Also, is this method (omitting the verb with the zu) frequently used in german? @Andreas

Comment: Andreas, welcome to the German Language StackExchange. If you like, you can take the [tour] or take a look at the [help]. There's also fun to be had in the [chat], as soon as you have earned enough magiv unicorn points. Have a nice day!

Comment: The claim that "zur" somehow replaces "to wear"/"zu tragen" seems questionable. @madijazz2: It is not common and I don't even think it is what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

> From a german magazine, "Der Trend zur stylishen Kopfbedeckung aber bleibt."

Indeed, "zur" somehow means "to"/"toward", as a "Trend" can be interpreted as a movement. If something is a trend, then more and more people adopt it, thereby they are figuratively "moving closer" toward the trending thing.

This idea is further supported when you look at two expressions common in German:

- "Trend (hin) zu etw." = a trend to do something, *toward* something
- "Trend (weg) von etw." = the opposite; more and more people abandon the formerly more popular thing, *away* from something

---

The second part of the question has already been answered accurately in [Andreas' answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27838/5999).